# How to highliht specific word in richtextbox during writing?

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I want to make an autocorrect for my language. I have a RichTextBox(name: MainText), where I write. during writing, the program should every word if it exists in a dictionary file. if not then change the specific word color to red. 
It has a timer. after every second it gets the written text and puts the words to an str array, and reads correct words from dictionary.txt file and puts them in a list. during comparison of the strings, it never highlights the incorrect words and it has always indexOutOfRange errors. How to fix it?

Here is the timer tick void:

```
void CheckTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> correct_words = File.ReadAllLines(DictPath).ToList();
        string text = MainText.Text;
        string[] Words = text.Split(' ', '.');

        for (int i = 0; i < Words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (correct_words.Contains(Words[i])) { }
            else
            {
                int index = 0;
                String temp = MainText.Text;
                MainText.Text = "";
                MainText.Text = temp;

                while (index < MainText.Text.LastIndexOf(Words[i]))
                {
                    MainText.Find(Words[i], index, MainText.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    MainText.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                    index = MainText.Text.IndexOf(Words[i], index) + 1;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

I also tried this void:

```
void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
    {
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        string s = box.Text;

        for (int ix = 0; ;)
        {
            int jx = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (jx < 0) break;
            box.SelectionStart = jx;
            box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
            box.SelectionColor = color;
            ix = jx + 1;
        }
        box.SelectionStart = pos;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
        box.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

This worked if I gave it a specific string, but it couldn't recognize the phrase input from the dictionary and gave the indexOutOfRange error.

Comment: did you try to Split the string & check word by word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public Form1()    
     {    
          InitializeComponent();    
      }    

      private void textbox1_TextChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)    
      {    
         string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split(',');    
         foreach(string word in words)    
         {    
             int startindex = 0;    
             while(startindex < richTextBox1.TextLength)    
             {    
                 int wordstartIndex = richTextBox1.Find(word, startindex, RichTextBoxFinds.None);    
                 if (wordstartIndex != -1)    
                 {    
                     richTextBox1.SelectionStart = wordstartIndex;    
                     richTextBox1.SelectionLength = word.Length;    
                     richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;    
                 }    
                 else    
                     break;    
                 startindex += wordstartIndex + word.Length;    
             }    
         }    
     }
```

Comment: Please include at least a brief explanation of what this code does and how it solves the problem in the question. It's not considered a good practice to only post a code block.

Comment: Your void marks all the correct words found in the dictionary file. How to make it mark all the misspelled words.

Comment: And This For Make Highlight

Answer (score 0):

For Clear Hightlight Use This Code

```
         richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;    
         richTextBox1.SelectAll();    
         richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
```